# How to ftp as root?

Tags: linux, root, ftp

I can ftp to a linux server by doing ftp server

But I can't do that with root.

Need sftp or something or what?

Comment: Are you saying you can't FTP when you are root on the local box or you can't be the root user on the remote box?

Comment: A safer option would be to use `sftp` witb a key file.

Comment: It's unclear why the user needs to use `ftp` with the root user.

Answer (score 2):

Don't FTP as root: the FTP protocol passes user ID and password as clear text (un-encrypted). If anyone catches the FTP login sequence, and there are sniffers that do exactly that, they have your root password.

That out of the way, it could be anything. You'll have to name the FTP server software.  Some won't allow a login if the user's local shell (on the machine running the FTP server) doesn't appear in `/etc/shells`, for example. Some FTP servers have very complicated ACL schemes about what to allow and what to disallow.